# Move address to the right and recipient to the left in a letter

Tags: formatting, document-classes, letters

I wanted to try to write letters in LaTeX but the problem about the layout of the letter is the fact that the sender's address is on the left and the recipient on the right but in French it is supposed to be the opposite. I wanted to know if it was possible to change that. I tried to use the `babel` package but it didn't change anything. This is the preamble of the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\address{my address} 
\signature{my name}
```

Comment: Note that Texmaker has nothing to do with this; it's a LaTeX question. There is a `lettre` class that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The class "lettre" seems to be working, I just need to find out how to use it now. Because texmaker would automatically show all environment in the class "letter".

Comment: @egreg Make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texmaker is only an editor and so it has nothing to do with the typesetting, which is done by the `letter` class.

The `letter` class is quite primitive and modeled on typical US commercial letter style. You probably want to look at the `lettre` class that specifically designed for French style letters.